# How to use OVAL to find CVEs

Tags: security

I need a way of finding CVEs for specific platforms (and not just necessarily desktop OS platforms). Been checking out the CVE and NVD websites, saw something called OVAL. Any good?

The idea is a user sets his operating system / software, along with its version number on my site, and I check against a vulnerability database to see if his current OS or software is vulnerable to attacks.
Does anyone have any experience in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OVAL ([Open Vulnerability & Assessment Language](https://oval.mitre.org)) is awesome. It represents the future of security automation.

There are two parts to using OVAL. The language itself defines different kinds of state that can be observed on a computer: file modes, file permissions, registry keys, etc. These states are combined into tests and definitions. For example, you might detect the presence or absence of a single, known vulnerability by looking for the presence of certain files and registry keys. Here is [an example of an OVAL definition](http://scapsync.com/oval_definition/oval%3aorg.mitre.oval%3adef:14146).

Once you have the *content* defined, you need an OVAL interpreter tool that can process those rules and actually evaluate them and report the results. Most of the high-end scanning products can use OVAL content -- especially the types of scanners used in the Fortune 500 -- but there are also some open source OVAL interpreters, too:

- http://oval.mitre.org/language/interpreter.html
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/ovaldi/